# How to copy a JarEntry to a directory

Tags: java, java-compiler-api

I have scanned the maven directory (.m2) and have filtered all the files ending with .jar.

```
List<File> jarFiles = scanRecursivelyForJarObjects(mavenRepository, fileManager);
```

I am trying the copy the .class files inside the JarFile to a different directory. Here is the code:

```
for(File jarFile : jarFiles) {
        Enumeration<JarEntry> enumeration = new JarFile(jarFile).entries();
        while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
            JarEntry jarEntry = enumeration.nextElement();
            if (!jarEntry.isDirectory() && jarEntry.getName().endsWith(".class")) {
                copyFile(new FileInputStream(jarEntry), classesDir.getAbsolutePath() + "\\" + jarEntry.getName());
            }
        }
    }
```

But it is throwing an error when I try to copy because jarEntry is not a File.

I am not sure how to convert jarEntry to a File.

Comment: You need to `copyStream`. I couldn't really believe it when I first started using Java that it didn't have such a method. afaik, is *still* doesn't. I wrote my own https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/12-copying-streams but commons io also has the same thing (I didn't know that at the time)

Comment: @g00se I am trying to cast JarEntry to a File type. Since only File types can be copied to FileOutputStream from FileInputStream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the input stream to the entry.

```
new JarFile(file).getInputStream(jarEntry)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
IOUtils.copyStream(jarEntry.getInputStream(), new FileOutputStream(new File(classesDir.getAbsolutePath(), jarEntry.getName())));
```